# Which compound interest formula would you use in this situation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\$38,900 is used to reduce a debt of \$900,000 immediately. Then \$3,055 is paid every month.

The interest rate would than be  fixed for the next 4 years at the rate of 4.3% p.a. (Does not say it is compounded).

What formula should be used to calculate how much debt is left after 4 years.

**Tried** I was going to use an annuity formula but that requires it to be compounded. 
I was thinking of using an excel spread sheet which would calculate the amount the debt has grown by then subtracting the /$3,005 from it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Depends on repayment schedule. Monthly? Biweekly? Is the $4.3\%$ the nominal yearly rate, with monthly compounding? Or is it the effective annual rate?

Comment: The spreadsheet is a fine answer-it will be correct.  A formula usually means you don't calculate month by month.  Compounding doesn't matter as long as you pay more than the interest every month.  There is no interest left next month to ask whether it should draw interest again.

Answer (score 1):

You now have a debt of $900,000-38,900=860,100$  For each month, you  can add the interest and deduct the payment to have the balance at the end of the month.  You have not specified what is to be computed-payment to retire the loan in four years, balance after specified payments, or??? When you ask "what formula" it suggests you have no interest in where the formulas come from or what their purpose is-you just want the answer.

Comment: I asked what formula should be used to calculate the debt after 4 years. Can I calculate the amount the debt would increase in 4 years then subtract the payments (which would be made in the same time period)?

Comment: In fact you can.  You can compound up the debt, then compound up each payment and subtract.  Adding up the compounded payments is summing a geometric series (each term has one more month of interest applied).  It is not obvious that this works, but you can prove it does.